# UIPickerView with UIButton

Tags: uibutton, uipickerview

I have my UIPickerView Data Source and Delegate running. When the user selects an option from the picker and then presses a button, It should state whether he is correct or wrong in an UILabel. There is only one correct answer and the rest are wrong. My code looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component

if (component == 0) {

return 2
[self.buttonDis setTitle:@"Correct!!!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {

return 1
[self.buttonDis setTitle:@"Wrong!!!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I only have 2 options (rows) in the UIPicker View and one component. When I run the application, however it does not display correct or wrong when the button is pressed.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like you're calling return before you're setting the title and not used a ;.  I.e. I would have thought it should read.

```
if (component == 0) 
{
    [self.buttonDis setTitle:@"Correct!!!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return 2;
} 
else  
{
    [self.buttonDis setTitle:@"Wrong!!!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: it still does not work. I am looking to set the button to change its label when pressed to correct when the user picks the Correct option from the picker, and wrong when he picks the rest